# Layout jumps up and down

Tags: java, android, xml

I am experiencing a problem in android activity layout. I have a TextView with an HTML formatted equation in it and the equation changes when user presses "previous" or "next" buttons. The strange problem is that when all eq coefficients are positive, all controls jump up an come back when eq has at least one negative coefficient. I would be grateful if anyone could advise on my problem.

XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eqTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="60dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/xLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="12"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/x1TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/x1EditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/x2TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/x2EditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="60sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="12"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prevButton"
            android:background="@drawable/prev_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:text="@string/prevButton"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="37sp" >

        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:background="@drawable/prev_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:text="@string/nextButton"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="37sp" >

        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/finButton"
            android:background="@drawable/fin_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="@string/finButton"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="37sp" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

One of onClickListeners:

```
eq.userAns[eq.counter][0] = x1EditText.getText().toString();
eq.userAns[eq.counter][1] = x2EditText.getText().toString();
eq.counter--;
nextButton.setEnabled(true);
nextButton.setAlpha(1);
eqTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(eq.equations[eq.counter]));
if (eq.counter == 0) {
        prevButton.setEnabled(false);
        prevButton.setAlpha((float) 0.5);
}
x1EditText.setText(eq.userAns[eq.counter][0]);
x2EditText.setText(eq.userAns[eq.counter][1]);
x1EditText.requestFocus();
```

If code supplied is not enough, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It seems the issue was with long minus sign as it adds additional white space above and below textview